# How to make my app's Python Docker image smaller?

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to make my Docker image smaller (4GB+ due to the large deep learning Python packages).

Two ideas that I’ve had so far:

1. Switch from `python:bullseye` to `python:slim-bullseye` to save 300MB.
2. Install packages with `--no-cache-dir` to prevent cached installs.

Any other ideas?

---

**Dockerfile**

```
# Debian OS
FROM python:3.7.12-bullseye

# ========= ROOT COMMANDS =========
# `jupyter lab` won't run as root, and root is bad practice.
# So we create a regular user.
RUN apt update
RUN apt install sudo

# Create user; 
RUN useradd --create-home --password RapidRigorReproduce aiqc_usr

# Make that user an admin; can't install apt-get dependencies without `sudo` prefix otherwise.
RUN usermod -aG sudo aiqc_usr

# Give that user permissions within their home directory, /var for apt-get, /usr/local for python packages.
RUN chown -R aiqc_usr /home/aiqc_usr /var /usr/local /usr/bin/dpkg /var/cache

# Switch to that user; root user's apt-get binaries are not shared w new user.
RUN su - aiqc_usr

# ========= USER COMMANDS =========
# Can't install nodejs without updating package manager.
# Only need to use the pw once when running sudo commands.
RUN echo "RapidRigorReproduce" | sudo -S apt update
RUN sudo apt upgrade -y
RUN sudo apt update

# Add the registry that contains node
RUN sudo apt -y install curl dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
# Install node
RUN sudo apt -y install nodejs

# For Sphinx documentation.
RUN sudo apt -y install pandoc

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# Developer packages
# Contains JupyterLab and I want this installed prior to plotly.
# Docker paths are can't access parent directories.
COPY requirements_dev.txt /
RUN pip install --default-timeout=100 -r requirements_dev.txt 
RUN rm requirements_dev.txt

# pip packages
# Installing plotly>=5.0.0 includes the prebuilt jupyter extension.
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --default-timeout=100 -r requirements.txt 
RUN rm requirements.txt

# Create a place to mount the source code so that it can be imported.
RUN mkdir /home/aiqc_usr/AIQC
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is two-phase builds. The image grows a lot when you include all the tools necessary to compile (native code compilation happens often without you knowing it inside `pip install`)

https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/

In pseudocode

```
FROM big AS big-image
RUN apt-get install gcc
FROM small AS runtime-image
COPY --from=big-image /tmp .
```